# How can I interpolate literal \t and \n in Perl strings?

Tags: perl

Say I have an environment variable `myvar`:

```
myvar=\tapple\n
```

When the following command will print out this variable

```
perl -e 'print "$ENV{myvar}"'
```

I will literally have `\tapple\n`, however, I want those control chars to be evaluated and not escaped. How would I achieve it?

In the real world `$ENV` residing in substitution, but I hope the answer will cover that.

Comment: Backing up a step, why do your environment variables have those sequences in them?

Comment: @brian d foy: because they are coming from text file, multiline and formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

```
perl -e 'print eval qq{"$ENV{myvar}"}'
```

UPD: You can also use substitution with the `ee` switch, which is safer:

```
perl -e '(my $s = $ENV{myvar}) =~ s/(\\n|\\t)/"qq{$1}"/gee; print $s'
```

Comment: Evaluating code direct from an environment variable? Sounds like a security risk.

Comment: It is a bit risky, but it seems like it's the answer for what Michael needed.

Comment: Don't do this. The string eval is often the sign that you need to learn more Perl. :)

Comment: @brian d foy: not really.  If you want to evaluate something exactly according to Perl's rules, `eval` is more likely to be correct than implementing it manually.  On the other hand, `eval` does a lot more than just translate "\t" to tabs -- it can also delete files :)

Comment: Well, eval can be correct if you know what you are doing, but that doesn't change my statement at all. Most times you still see a string eval, it's not correct, meaning it does what you want without doing what you don't want (or don't know about). Just because you know how to use it properly doesn't negate "most" or "often". :)

Answer (score 2):

You should probably be using `String::Escape`.

```
use String::Escape qw(unbackslash);

my $var = unbackslash($ENV{'myvar'});
```

`unbackslash` unescapes any string escape sequences it finds, turning them into the characters they represent.  If you want to explicitly only translate `\n` and `\t`, you'll probably have to do it yourself with a `s`ubstitution as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835423/how-can-i-interpolate-literal-t-and-n-in-perl-strings/2835561#2835561).

Comment: My only concern here is that `unprintable` might translate much more than you are willing to accept.

Comment: That's a good point.  Lemme reflect that...

Comment: This answer sounds like the opposite of what he wants to do.  "I want those control chars to be evaluated and not escaped," he writes.  So it seems like "unbackslash" is the function he wants from that module.

Comment: Inaccurate; `unprintable` is one of the evaluation functions.  That said, I'll take your advice and the perldoc's and recommend `unbackslash`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing particularly special about a sequence of characters that includes a `\`. If you want to substitute one sequence of characters for another, it's very simple to do in Perl:

```
my %sequences = (
      '\\t' => "\t",
      '\\n' => "\n",
      'foo' => 'bar',
      );

 my $string = '\\tstring fool string\\tfoo\\n';

 print "Before: [$string]\n";
 $string =~ s/\Q$_/$sequences{$_}/g for ( keys %sequences );
 print "After: [$string]\n";
```

The only trick with \ is to keep track of the times when Perl thinks it's an escape character.

```
Before: [\tstring fool string\tfoo\n]
After: [    string barl string  bar
]
```

However, as [darch notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835423/how-can-i-interpolate-literal-t-and-n-in-perl-strings/2837142#2837142), you might just be able to use [String::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/dist/String::Escape).

Note that you have to be extremely careful when you're taking values from environment variables. I'd be reluctant to use `String::Escape` since it might process quite a bit more than you are willing to translate. The safe way is to only expand the particular values you explicitly want to allow. See my "Secure Programming Techniques" chapter in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242) where I talk about this, along with the taint checking you might want to use in this case.